# How to edit OpenCart meta head tag

Tags: opencart

How to edit OpenCart **meta head** tag.  where is the file in OpenCart  ? 
In cPanel there is no layout.tpl file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meta information is edited entirely via the admin interface in OpenCart.

Navigate to your admin panel and go to:

`System > Settings > (In the Action Column) Edit > General Tab`

Technically you can edit the `header.tpl` file for your template but I would advise against this because OpenCart allows you to operate multiple different domain/themed website via the same installation and therefore you can have unique meta information for each of these sites. This is only achievable if your meta information is evaluated per store where if you manually edited and hard coded the meta information you could only have 1 set of meta information per template theme.

Answer (score 0):

Meta Tag Description and Meta Tag Keyword is edited admin side in OpenCart.

Login to your admin panel :

And Go TO  :

> System > Settings > Edit > General Tab

**See Screenshot :**

[image]